# Use full names in url, instead of something like "index.php?id=0"

Tags: php, web

Last year I created my own website from scratch. Although it is nothing big, I would like to improve it by replacing awkward, hard to remember, URLs.

So, I would very much like to move from "http://www.iubuntu.cz/index.php?id=0" to "http://www.iubuntu.cz/" and from "http://www.iubuntu.cz/index.php?id=1" to "http://www.iubuntu.cz/desktop".

Can someone please redirect me to some info about this? I was trying to find something through Google, but it seems I am unable to ask a proper question.

Thank you very much.

Comment: use the url rewrite in .htaccess file.

Comment: use can use htacesss and url-rewrite ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For makng your website url user friendly and SEO friendly you can do it by URL rewriting. That's mean your original Url will mapped to a SEO friendly custom url.
e.g. "http://www.iubuntu.cz/index.php?id=0" to "http://www.iubuntu.cz/desktop".

To do this you need to know .htaccess. Here is the sample of url rewriting using htaccess.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^Users/home$ http://www.example.com/ [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^index.php$ http://www.example.com/ [L,R=301] 
</IfModule>
```

To know more check this link, it is very useful. 
http://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Answer (score 3):

You need to look into using URL rewriting with .htaccess.

[Here's](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/02/introduction-to-url-rewriting/) an intro article by Smashing Magazine.